# Create default variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce plugin to create an e-shop with Wordpress. All the products will have the same variations and the same price.

There will be many products, is there any way to create variations by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some really handy tools I've used for variations:

This plugin allows you to import all of your attributes/variations (and other product information) from a CSV or XML file. So you could very easily apply the same variations to many products:
wpallimport.com

Or this one is handy for applying the same attributes to many products: http://www.najeebmedia.com/n-media-woocommerce-personalized-product-options-manager/

I would much prefer the first plugin, however, as I'm currently using both for a project.

Feel free to contact me on Facebook if you'd like to discuss further! (facebook.com/kingd18)
Dan